# Java Sample Code Runtime Error

Tags: java, runtime

This is probably an elementary question. However, I have completed reading the 12th Chapter of Java Programming for the Absolute Beginner and have approached some sample code. I get a compiler error when I try to compile this sample code program. I have all the related programs located within the same package, so this is not the problem.

The error occurs at this line:

```
minefield.addMineFieldListener(this);
```

It states:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code 
- Erroneous sym type: MineField.addMineFieldListener at MinePatrol.<init>
(MinePatrol.java:21)
```

My main question is: Why is this occuring?

Thank you very much for your time and cooperation reagrding this matter.

HERE IS THE CODE FOR MinePatrol.java:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

public class MinePatrol extends GUIFrame
                    implements MineFieldListener, ActionListener {
protected MineField minefield;
protected Button resetButton;
protected Label flagCountLabel;

public MinePatrol() {
super("MinePatrol");
minefield = new MineField(10, 10, 10);
minefield.addMineFieldListener(this);
add(minefield, BorderLayout.CENTER);
MediaTracker mt = new MediaTracker(this);
Image[] imgs = {
  Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("flag.gif"),
  Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("mine.gif"),
  Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("explode.gif") };

for (int i=0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
  mt.addImage(imgs[i], i);
}
try {
  mt.waitForAll();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {}
minefield.setImages(imgs[0], imgs[1], imgs[2]);
try {
  minefield.setAudioClips(
    Applet.newAudioClip(new URL("file:reveal.wav")),
    Applet.newAudioClip(new URL("file:flag.wav")),
    Applet.newAudioClip(new URL("file:unflag.wav")),
    Applet.newAudioClip(new URL("file:explode.wav")));
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {}

flagCountLabel = new Label("Flags: 10", Label.CENTER);
add(flagCountLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
resetButton = new Button("Reset");
resetButton.addActionListener(this);
add(resetButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
pack();
setVisible(true);
  }

public static void main(String args[]) {
new MinePatrol();
}

public void mineFieldSolved(MineFieldEvent e) {
flagCountLabel.setText("You Win!");
}

 public void mineFieldRandomized(MineFieldEvent e) {
 flagCountLabel.setText("Flags: " + minefield.getMineCount());
}

 public void mineFieldDetonated(MineFieldEvent e) {
 flagCountLabel.setText("You exploded into tiny bits... RIP");
}

 public void mineFieldFlagCountChanged(MineFieldEvent e) {
 flagCountLabel.setText("Flags: "
  + (minefield.getMineCount() - minefield.getFlagCount()));
 }

 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  minefield.randomize();
  }

 }
```

Here is the code for MineField.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.applet.AudioClip;

public class MineField extends Panel 
                    implements MineCellListener {
protected int rows, cols, mines, flagged, revealed;
protected AudioClip  revealClip, flagClip, unflagClip, explodeClip;
protected MineCell[][] cells;
//keeps track of MineCell indices
protected Hashtable pointIndex;
protected Vector listeners;

   public MineField(int nRows, int nCols, int nMines) {
   rows = nRows > 0 ? nRows : 1;
   cols = nCols > 0 ? nCols : 1;
   cells = new MineCell[rows][cols];
   mines = nMines >= 0 && nMines < rows * cols ? nMines : 1;
   pointIndex = new Hashtable(rows * cols);
   setLayout(new GridLayout(rows, cols));
   for (int r=0; r < cells.length; r++) {
       for (int c=0; c < cells[r].length; c++) {
           cells[r][c] = new MineCell();
           cells[r][c].addMineCellListener(this);
           //Points use (x, y) coordinates to x=c and y=r
           pointIndex.put(cells[r][c], new Point(c, r));
           cells[r][c].setSize(25, 25);
           add(cells[r][c]); 
       }
       }
   listeners = new Vector();
   randomizeField(false);
   }

   protected void randomizeField(boolean fireEvent) {
       Random rand = new Random();
       int index;
   //initialize empty
   for (int r=0; r < cells.length; r++) {
       for (int c=0; c < cells[r].length; c++) {
           cells[r][c].resetContents(MineCell.EMPTY);
       }
   }
   //randomly place all mines
   for (int m=0; m < mines; m++) {
      do {
          index = rand.nextInt(rows * cols);
      }
      while (cells[index / cols][index % cols].getContents() != MineCell.EMPTY);
      cells[index / cols][index % cols].resetContents(MineCell.MINE);
   }
   setNumberClues();
   flagged = revealed = 0;
   //does not fire flagCountChanged, only mineFieldRandomized
   if (fireEvent) (new EventThread(new MineFieldEvent(this,
                                MineFieldEvent.RANDOMIZED))).start();
   }

    public void randomize() {
     randomField(true);
    }

    public int getFlagCount() {
    return flagged;
    }

   public int getMineCount() {
       return mines;
   }

  //counts and sets the number of mines surrounding each cell
   protected void setNumberClues() {
   int nMines;
   for (int r=0; r < cells.length; r++) {
       for (int c=0; c < cells[r].length; c++) {
           if (cells[r][c].getContents() != MineCell.MINE) {
               nMines = 0;
               //count the number of mines surrounding this cell
               for (int dr = r - 1; dr <= r + 1; dr++) {
                   //prevent ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
                   //continue puts control back to the beginning of the loop
                   if (dr < 0 || dr >= cells.length) continue;
                   for (int dc = c -1; dc <= c + 1; dc++) {
                       if (dc < 0 || dc >= cells[dr].length) continue;
                       if (cells[dr][dc].getContents() == MineCell.MINE) nMines++;
                   }
               }
               cells[r][c].resetContents(nMines);
               }
           }
       }
   }

     public class MineFieldEvent extends java.util.EventObject {
protected int eventID;
//event id constants
public final static int SOLVED = 0,
                            RANDOMIZED = 1,
                            DETONATED = 2,
                            FLAG_COUNT_CHANGED = 3;

    public MineFieldEvent(Object source, int id) {
    super(source);
    eventID = id;
    }

    public int getID() {
        return eventID;
        }
    }
   protected class EventThread extends Thread {
   MineFieldEvent e;
   EventThread(MineFieldEvent mfe) {
       e = mfe;
   }
      public void addMineFieldListener(MineFieldListener mfl) {
   listeners.addElement(mfl);
   }

   public void removeMineFieldListener(MineFieldListener mfl) {
       listeners.removeElement(mfl);
   }

   public void run() {
    switch(e.getID()) {
case MineFieldEvent.SOLVED:
for (int i=0; i < listeners.size(); i++) {
((MineFieldListener)listeners.elementAt(i)).mineFieldSolved(e);
}
break;
case MineFieldEvent.RANDOMIZED:
for (int i=0; i < listeners.size(); i++) {
((MineFieldListener)listeners.elementAt(i)).mineFieldRandomized(e);
}
break;
case MineFieldEvent.DETONATED:
for (int i=0; i < listeners.size(); i++) {
((MineFieldListener)listeners.elementAt(i)).mineFieldDetonated(e);
}
break;
case MineFieldEvent.FLAG_COUNT_CHANGED:
for (int i=0; i < listeners.size(); i++) {
((MineFieldListener)listeners.elementAt(i)).mineFieldFlagCountChanged(e);
}
break;
}
}
}

   public void setImages(Image f, Image m, Image e) {
   MineCell.setImages(f, m, e);
   }

   public void setAudioClips(AudioClip r, AudioClip f, AudioClip u,
                            AudioClip e) {
   revealClip = r; flagClip = f; unflagClip = u; explodeClip = e;
   }

   /* Reveals areas mine-free minecells */
    protected void showSafeArea(MineCell start) {
   //get the point index for the starting cell
   Point p = (Point)pointIndex.get(start);
   for (int r = p.y - 1; r <= p.y + 1; r++) {
       if (r < 0 || r >= cells.length) continue;
       for (int c = p.x - 1; c <= p.x + 1; c++) {
           if (c < 0 || c >= cells[r].length || !cells[r][c].isHidden())
               continue;
           if (cells[r][c].isFlagged()) {
               flagged--;

              (new EventThread(new MineFieldEvent(this, 
                                    MineFieldEvent.FLAG_COUNT_CHANGED))).start();
           }
           cells[r][c].setHidden(false);
           revealed++;
           if(cells[r][c].getContents() == MineCell.EMPTY)
               showSafeArea(cells[r][c]);
            }
       }
   }

   protected void checkIfSolved() {
       if (flagged + revealed == rows * cols) {
       //solved if we get here.
       revealAll();
       (new EventThread(new MineFieldEvent(this,
                                MineFieldEvent.SOLVED))).start();
       }
    }

   public void revealAll() {
       for (int r=0; r < cells.length; r++) {
           for (int c =0; c < cells.length; c++) {
           cells[r][c].setHidden(false);
           }
       }
   }

    public void mineCellRevealed(MineCellEvent e) {
        if (revealClip != null) revealClip.play();
       revealed++;
       if ((MineCell)e.getSource()).getContents() == MineCell.EMPTY)
        showSafeArea((MineCell)e.getSource());
        checkIfSolved();
   }

    public void mineCellDetonated(MineCellEvent e) {
   //game over show all
   if (explodeClip != null) explodeClip.play();
   revealAll();
   (new EventThread(new MineFieldEvent(this, 
                           MineFieldEvent.DETONATED))).start();
    }

    public void mineCellFlagged(MineCellEvent e) {
         if (flagged >= mines) {
          ((MineCell)e.getSource()).getHidden(true);
          return;
   }
   if (flagClip != null) flagClip.play();
   flagged++;
   (new EventThread(new MineFieldEvent(this,
                            MineFieldEvent.FLAG_COUNT_CHANGED))).start();
   checkIfSolved();
   }

   public void mineCellUnflagged(MineCellEvent e) {
   if (unflagClip != null) unflagClip.play();
   flagged--;
   (new EventThread(new MineFieldEvent(this, 
                             MineFieldEvent.FLAG_COUNT_CHANGED))).start();
   }




                   }
```

Comment: `RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code`  Sounds like you are using an IDE and ignoring compilation problems.  Don't do that.  Further tip, compile often.

Comment: Better switch on that auto build flag

Comment: It would help to see your `MineField` class source.

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - what can cause this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333285/java-lang-runtimeexception-uncompilable-source-code-what-can-cause-this)

Comment: @PeterLawrey This is Not a duplicate, look at who wrote that question - MalcolmTucker not user1604490.  He also did not include code.

Comment: @JoshDM I have added my MineField class. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Line 21: minefield.addMineFieldListener(this);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be the [NetBeans bug 199293](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=199293). It is fixed now but not yet old. If you use NetBeans, check maybe you need to update. The error message *Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym
type matches* and I do not see anything in your code to result an error message so wise. Try to build with Eclipse or Ant.

Answer (score 0):

minefield.addMineFieldListener(this); 
what do you want using "this" ?