# return Object [] [] gives RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code

Tags: java, arrays, object, nullpointerexception

I have written a method that will return an `Object[][]` to use as the data for a `JTable`. I read the data in from a Microsoft Access Database and then put each piece of information into a cell in the `Object [][]`. My problem is the return statement of my method which gives me a `RuntimeException`. When I use a `System.out.println()` to print out each element of the object all the data is there and it works fine, but when it gets to the returning of that object then it falls through.

```
public Object [] [] AllWorldBestTimes() throws SQLException
{
  DatabaseConnection connection = new DatabaseConnection();

  ResultSet result = connection.SelectStatements("SELECT * FROM WorldBestTimes");

  count = 24;

  Object [] [] data = new String[count][4];    

    int row = 0;

    while(row < count)
    {
        data [row][0] = result.getString(1); 
        data [row][1] = result.getString(2);
        data [row][2] = result.getString(3);
        data [row][3] = result.getString(4);
        result.next();  

        System.out.println(data [row][0]);
        System.out.println(data [row][1]);
        System.out.println(data [row][2]);
        System.out.println(data [row][3]);

        row++;
    }

    connection.close();

    return data;
}
```

The above code displays the exact data that needs to be returned when it is printed out but returning it gives me a `RuntimeException`.

**UPDATE**

Stacktrace:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - unreported exception java.sql.SQLException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Comment: 'returning it gives me a NullPointerException' does not make sense. Please show the stacktrace

Comment: Returning it? Or maybe when printing out that data?

Comment: Maybe try to append to `""` String or check if `getString()` is `null` so you can throw NPE yourself?

Comment: @IgorRodriguez Absolutely **not**. if a string (or an object in general) is null and you print it, then it will print `null`, if you **try to use** a null object, it will throw a `NullPointerException`, but printing a null object doesn't throw it

Comment: but when i print it out all the data is there. its only returning it that i get the problem.

Comment: @user2513354 **Where is the stack trace?**

Comment: @user2513354 **Post the full stack trace**. Without it we can only guess what is the error, but we can't be sure if you don't post the stack trace

Comment: The actual object[][] has all the data it needs to because i can print it out just fine. I ran a debugger and it gives the nullpointerexception on the return statement

Comment: Whats is the stacktrace?

Comment: @user2513354 The stacktrace is the line that says something like `Exception in thread main: java.lang.NullPointerException at .......`

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - unreported exception java.sql.SQLException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Comment: @user2513354 Why did you say `NullPointerException`?

Answer (score 4):

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - unreported exception java.sql.SQLException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

This means you are running code which doesn't compile.  Some IDE's allow this such as eclipse and this is a VERY BAD IDEA in my opinion as it means you maximise the cost of finding and fixing those errors.  I suggest you turn this feature off.

[java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - what can cause this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333285/java-lang-runtimeexception-uncompilable-source-code-what-can-cause-this)

---

I would write this code very different if you can.  Opening and closing a database connection is very expensive. You can use a `List<String[]>` to read all the rows instead of assuming there is 24.

```
public String[][] AllWorldBestTimes() throws SQLException {
    return select("SELECT * FROM WorldBestTimes");
}

public String[][] select(String selectSQL) throws SQLException {
    // TODO use a connection pool instead.
    Connection connection = new DatabaseConnection();
    List<String[]> data;
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    ResultSet result = null;
    try {
        statement = connection.prepareStatement(selectSQL);
        result = statement.executeQuery();
        data = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        int columnCount = result.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
        while (result.next()) {
            String[] row = new String[columnCount];
            for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
                row[i] = result.getString(i + 1);
            data.add(row);
        }
    } finally {
        if (result != null) {
            result.close();
        }
        if (statement != null) {
            statement.close();
        }
        connection.close();
    }
    return data.toArray(new String[data.size()][]);

    }
}
```

Comment: The number of rows might actually be the cause of the error. Suppose there are less than 24.

Comment: @Ingo I thought of that, but I wouldn't expect result.getString() or result.next() to throw an NPE, an SQLException would make more sense.  Perhaps the OP is not printing the error correctly.

Comment: Well, in fact it is an SQLException, the OP written it wrong.

Comment: He's not actually getting an `SQLException`. He's getting a compilation error because he does not catch or declare an `SQLException` somewhere and then he's getting an "Uncompilable source code" exception because he's running code that did not fully compile.

Comment: @sepp2k Thank you, I have updated my answer.  It amazes me that people inflict this feature on themselves willingly.

Answer (score 2):

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - unreported exception java.sql.SQLException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

This error message indicates that you are running a partially compiled program and the part that failed to compile, did so because it called a method that may throw an `SQLException` without either catching that exception or declaring `throws SQLException`. Since the given method actually does declare `throws SQLException`, I assume that the error is actually in a different method (probably the one that calls this one).

Note that this excpetion does not indicate that any SQLException is actually thrown - only that it might be thrown and you don't account for that possibility.