# Connecting main class to other classes

Tags: java, netbeans

I am writing a program in java were I have to make a class (InvoiceTest) that will have main in it and a second class (Invoice). When I run the main InvoiceTest class it should show the message in the Invoice class. I keep getting an error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at InvoiceTest.main(InvoiceTest.java:4)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - constructor Invoice() is already defined in class Invoice
    at Invoice.<clinit>(Invoice.java:20)
    ... 1 more
```

I dont know what to do, please let me know what I am doing wrong and any suggestions on how to fix it. Thanks

```
public class InvoiceTest{
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Invoice invoiceObject = new Invoice();
        invoiceObject.simpleMessage();
    }
}

// This is the second class. I am using NetBeans so each class is in its own window.

public class Invoice {        
    public void simpleMessage() {
        System.out.println("This is another class");
    }
}
```

Comment: `constructor Invoice() is already defined in class Invoice at Invoice.` instead of window you mean different files?

Comment: this is your complete code??

Comment: Yes for now, I just started so I will be adding on. What did you mean by decode?

Comment: check this old thread on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333285/java-lang-runtimeexception-uncompilable-source-code-what-can-cause-this

Comment: i tried to reproduce your error but nothing... i used default-package, no constructor declaration.. do you have the classes in a project?

Comment: dear @user2005617, could you please check if there's another class in the same classpath with the same name? Another way to check this.. change the name of your class `Invoice` to `InvoiceX` or something like that.

Comment: @zEro but this would get a compile time error rather than a runtimeexception i guess.. but whos knows xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need two separate classes.  One class works.

```
public class Invoice {        
    public void simpleMessage() {
        System.out.println("This is another class");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Invoice invoiceObject = new Invoice();
        invoiceObject.simpleMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you mean by separate? Into different files?

Comment: @user2005617: You defined two separate classes, Invoice and InvoiceTest.  I've always had the main method instantiate the class that contains the main method, so that's what I put in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are they both in the same `.java` file? The java compiler requires exactly one java class per source file.

Comment: did you decode this ? `I am using NetBeans so each class is in its own window.`

Comment: no they are in different files. How would I put them in one file?

Comment: @nachokk When I wrote this answer, that comment wasn't there.

Comment: package them into the same package will solve the problem instantly

Answer (score 0):

Strange error indeed.

How about adding back the constructor for the class `Invoice` ?

public Invoice(){
}