# java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: <any>.setVisible

Tags: java, netbeans-7

My code was working just well on netbeans then suddenly it stopped recognising jframe elements and he it kept giving this error "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: .setVisible" each time i run it even after clearing the cache...........how can i solve this?

I deleted everything under netbeans/6.9/var/cache/index/ but it still shows the whole form as erroneous. After some advice from

[java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - what can cause this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333285/java-lang-runtimeexception-uncompilable-source-code-what-can-cause-this)