# how to sort ArrayList objects by their boolean fields

Tags: java, arraylist, comparator

Hi i have an ArrayList of custom objects. I am able to sort these by their int and String fields with the code below:

```
public class ArtistNameComparator implements Comparator<MP3Track>{

    @Override
    public int compare(MP3Track t1, MP3Track t2) {
        return t1.getArtist().compareTo(t2.getArtist());
    }
}
```

and

```
public class TrackNoComparator implements Comparator<MP3Track>{

    @Override
    public int compare(MP3Track t1, MP3Track t2) {
        try{
            if(t1.getTrackNo() > t2.getTrackNo())
                return 1;
            else if(t1.getTrackNo() < t2.getTrackNo())
                return -1;
            else
                return 0;
        }//Debug this possibility
        catch(NullPointerException e){
            throw new NullPointerException(e + "...compare int comparator!.");
        }
    }
}
```

but if I try and sort the list by their boolean field with either of the below examples:

```
public class FavoriteComparator implements Comparator<MP3Track>{

    @Override
    public int compare(MP3Track t1, MP3Track t2) {
        boolean v1 = t1.getFav();
        boolean v2 = t2.getFav();
        return Boolean.compare( v1, v2 );
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(MP3Track t1, MP3Track t2) {
        boolean v1 = t1.getFav();
        boolean v2 = t2.getFav();
        if( v1 && ! v2 ) {
            return +1;
        }
        if( ! v1 && v2 ) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I get the following message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: 
      Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: java.util.Collections.sort 
      at mp3_box.MP3Catalogue.sortTracks(MP3Catalogue.java:88) 
      at mp3_box.MP3Player.main(MP3Player.java:56) Java Result: 1
```

I new to Java and would appreciate it if someone could explain why this is wrong?

Many thanks in advance..

It is called from here:

```
public void sortTracks(){
    String choice = null;
    System.out.println(face.getSortCatalogueMenu());
    System.out.print("ENTER->");
    try{
        choice = (keyboard.readString().trim().toLowerCase());
    }
    catch(InvalidUserInputException e){
        System.err.println(e + "Error in sortTracks");
    }
    switch (choice) {
        case "n":
            Collections.sort(vector, new TrackNoComparator());
            System.out.println("Your MP3 Catalogue has been sorted by Track Number");
            break;
        case "t":
            Collections.sort(vector, new TrackNameComparator());
            System.out.println("Your MP3 Catalogue has bee sorted by Track Name");
            break;
        case "a":
            Collections.sort(vector, new ArtistNameComparator());
            System.out.println("Your MP3 Catalogue has been sorted by Artist Name");
            break;
        case "b":
            Collections.sort(vector, new AlbumNameComparator());
            System.out.println("Your MP3 Catalogue has been sorted by Album Name");
            break;
        case "f":
            Collections.sort(vector, new FavoriteComparator());
            break;
        case "x":
            return;
    }
    for (MP3Track t : vector) 
        System.out.println(t);
}//End sortTrack
```

and thats called from main here:

```
    String choice = "";
    while(!(choice.equals("e"))){
        System.out.println(face.getMainMenu());
        System.out.print("ENTER->");
        try{
            choice = (keyboard.readString().trim().toLowerCase());
        }
        catch(InvalidUserInputException e){
        System.out.println("InvalidUsedInputException thrown " + e.getMessage());
        }
        switch (choice){
            case "h":
                MP3Cat.shuffleTracks();
                break; 
            case "d":
                MP3Cat.deleteTrack();
                break;
            case "a":
                MP3Cat.addTrack();
                break;
            case "w":
                MP3Cat.swapTrack();
                break;
            case "s":
                MP3Cat.catSearch();
                break;
            case "i":
                MP3Cat.trackInfo();
                break;
            case "t":
                MP3Cat.sortTracks();
                break;
            case "r":
                MP3Cat.exploreTracks();
                break;
            case "f":
                MP3Cat.favorites();<---------
            case "x":
                System.exit(1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `+1`is not valid code. It should be `return 1`

Comment: strange, return +1 compiles for me.  What line is the compiler error pointing too?

Comment: `return +1` is valid, because `+1` is evaluated as `1`.

Comment: Add your main class code where you call the sort.

Comment: I tried 1 & +1 but no joy!!!

Comment: Here is the full message: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: java.util.Collections.sort
 at mp3_box.MP3Catalogue.sortTracks(MP3Catalogue.java:88)
 at mp3_box.MP3Player.main(MP3Player.java:56)
Java Result: 1

Comment: Maybe this question is of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333285/java-lang-runtimeexception-uncompilable-source-code-what-can-cause-this

Comment: @devconsole - many thanks thats sorted it!!!

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to define two methods with the same signature in one class but you have duplicate `public int compare(MP3Track t1, MP3Track t2)`

Comment: This.  OP, remove one of the `compare` implementations from your FavoriteComparator.

Comment: Apologies I its the way that I have shown what I tried. I have tried both of the compare methods separately.