# Java- RuntimeException- Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, runtimeexception

I'm new in Java also I'm new in this website, so I'm sorry if the error is obvious, but  I got an error, that I dont know what it means, I have try everything to fix it.

I'm currently writing a basic aplication library, with some swing interface, but the problem is when trying to create a window of the form of books, there is the relevant code.

This is the principal window.

```
 public class VentanaPrincipal extends javax.swing.JFrame {

   public VentanaPrincipal() {
     initComponents();
     this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}

private void bt_salirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    EscribirBinario escritor = new EscribirBinario();
    //   Collections.sort(ListaClientes.clientes);

    if (escritor.abrir(Main.archivo1)) {
        for (int indice = 0; indice < ListaClientes.clientes.size(); indice++) {
            escritor.escribir(ListaClientes.clientes.get(indice));
        }
        escritor.cerrar();
    }
    System.exit(0);
}                                        

private void bt_clienteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

    MantenimientoCliente clientes = new MantenimientoCliente(this, true);
    clientes.setVisible(true);
}                                          

private void bt_libroActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    MantenimientoLibro book = new MantenimientoLibro(this, true);
    book.setVisible(true);
}                                                    

   }
```

There are the code of the form of books.

```
 public class MantenimientoLibro extends javax.swing.JDialog {

  public MantenimientoLibro() {
   }

public MantenimientoLibro(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
    super(parent, modal);
    initComponents();

    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}


public MantenimientoLibro(java.awt.Dialog parent, boolean modal) {
    super(parent, modal);
    initComponents();
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

}           

private void bt_salirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    this.dispose();
}                                        

private void bt_insertarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    FormularioLibro formulario = new FormularioLibro(this, true);

    formulario.setVisible(true);
    this.dispose();

}
```

}

And this is the error i got:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: TareaP2.MantenimientoLibro
at TareaP2.VentanaPrincipal.bt_libroActionPerformed(VentanaPrincipal.java:130)
at TareaP2.VentanaPrincipal.access$100(VentanaPrincipal.java:11)
at TareaP2.VentanaPrincipal$2.actionPerformed(VentanaPrincipal.java:51)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: hope this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333285/java-lang-runtimeexception-uncompilable-source-code-what-can-cause-this

Comment: @AndrewThompson SSCCE won't be of any help if you are on Eclipse. ;-) NetBeans issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [bug report here](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=199293).  It has the solution to your problem:

```
From the nbusers mailing list I got the following hint:

"workaround it by deselecting 'Compile On Save' in the project options".
```

The answer pointed out by Mark in the comments also goes along the same line. Here is the link again:
[java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - what can cause this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333285/java-lang-runtimeexception-uncompilable-source-code-what-can-cause-this)

Comment: This will just reveal the real compilation error, it won't actually solve the problem. The problem will be solved by fixing the compilation error.

Comment: Yes  you are right. I am assuming that OP does not know where the error is.

Comment: This helped with NetBeans 12.6.

Answer (score 1):

Exiting Netbeans and starting the compilar again resolved the issue.