# does not override method error

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract

I'm getting this exception thrown in my java code when trying to run the file.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at DemoLexer.<clinit>(GenLexer.java:309)
at LexerDemo.main(GenLexer.java:325)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - MH_Lexer.VarAcceptor is not abstract and does not override abstract method dead(int) in GenAcceptor
Lexer>  at GenAcceptor.<clinit>(GenLexer.java:14)
... 2 more
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

The issue is that my `VarAcceptor` class has a clearly defined and implemented `dead(int)` method and that file itself doesn't show any errors, which it otherwise does when you don't implement the methods properly so I don't know how to solve this, seeing that the error makes no sense to me with the method in question being implemented correctly. I have also added the `@Override` annotation to the method.

```
  static class VarAcceptor extends GenAcceptor implements DFA {

    @Override
    boolean dead(int state) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Interface GenAcceptor:

```
abstract class GenAcceptor {

    abstract String lexClass() ;
    abstract int numberOfStates() ;
    abstract int nextState (int state, char input) ;
    abstract boolean accepting (int state) ;
    abstract boolean dead (int state) ;
}
```

Comment: please post the code

Comment: You need to add the actual code if we are gonna help you at all.

Comment: Ok i added the code in question

Comment: So where's `GenAcceptor`?

Comment: GenAcceptor where is that?

Comment: all it has is the method declarations and code not relevant to the issue but ill add it if it helps

Comment: added the genacceptor

Comment: did you import GenAcceptor?

Comment: I only have this `import java.io.*;` but its not throwing any errors which it usually does if u forget to import stuff

Comment: what IDE do you use?

Comment: ok put your cursor right after GenAcceptor and press Ctrl + Space

Comment: do you mean in the static class extends line or in the original place I declared genAcceptor?

Comment: public class VarAcceptor extends GenAcceptor implements DFA

Comment: try that that should work

Comment: The thing is the static declerations were given to us in the exercise so I think that's how its supposed to stay

Comment: Possible similar useful question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333285/java-lang-runtimeexception-uncompilable-source-code-what-can-cause-this

Comment: Yep that solved it @AdamP, post it as an answer, I'll accept

Comment: Adam I guest you won

Comment: Turned out to be a netbeans error rather than anything in my code. Changing the settings solved the issue

Comment: Okay, I could not figure it out because your code did look right but that is great you figured it out,   Take Care

Answer (score 0):

You can't return 0 from a boolean method

Comment: That was just an example, I'm not returning 0...please remove this if you can as the problem was solved in the comments

Answer (score 0):

[java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - what can cause this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333285/java-lang-runtimeexception-uncompilable-source-code-what-can-cause-this)

The error is described in this link. It is a netbeans issue which requires turning off a setting in project properties.